# Convert a float literal to int representation in x86 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86, ieee-754

The following C code:

```c
int main()
{
    float f;
    f = 3.0;
}
```

Is converted to the following assembly instructions:

```x86
main:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  subl $16, %esp
  flds .LC0
  fstps -4(%ebp)
  movl $0, %eax
  leave
  ret
.LC0:
  .long 1077936128
```

What is the correct way to calculate the `.long`/`int` representation of the `float` literal?

*e.g.* `1077936128` generated from `3.0` for the example shown above

---

> For this example `gcc` is used with the `-m32 -S -O0 -fno-stack-protector -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` flags using intel settings to generate the assembly output.

**References**:

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/g/X6mgaT)  with compilation flags and other settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x86 FPU hardware uses [IEEE754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) / binary64 representations for `float` / `double`.

Determining the IEEE 754 representation of a floating point number is not trivial for humans.  In handwritten assembly code, it's usually a good idea to use the `.float` or `.double` directives instead:

```
.float 3.0    # generates 3.0 as a 32 bit float
.double 3.0   # generates 3.0 as a 64 bit float
```

---

If you really want to compute this manually, refer to the [explanations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  It might be interesting to do so as an exercise, but for actual programming it's tedious and mostly useless.

Compilers do the conversion (with rounding to the nearest representable FP value) internally, because FP values often don't come directly from a literal in the source; they can come from constant folding.  e.g. `1.23 * 4.56` is evaluated at compile time, so the compiler already ends up with FP values in float or double binary representation.  Printing them back to decimal for the assembler to parse and re-convert to binary would be slower and might require a lot of decimal places.

---

To compute the representation of a 32 bit float as a 32 bit integer, you can use [an online IEEE754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), or a program like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union { uint32_t u32; float f32; } intfloat;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s some-number\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    intfloat.f32 = atof(argv[1]);

    printf("0x%08" PRIx32 "\n", intfloat.u32);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Do you know of C source code for this functionality?

Comment: Here's a great online tool for `IEEE 754` conversions: [FloatConverter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: @janniks I have added a program that does this.   If you ever write assembly code, please never encode floating point literals as integers.  That's just terrible for the next person to read your code.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use `.float` for floats in most cases - maybe use the conversion for some proof-of-concept optimizations...

Comment: `unsigned long` may vary from C implementation to C implementation.It would be better to use `uint32_t`. Then the `printf` needs to use `"0x%08" PRIx32 "\n"`. `float` may vary too (although four bytes is overwhelmingly common), so testing its size would not be a bad idea. (Also, there is no need for parentheses on `return` statements, and `u32` is a more common and clear name for an unsigned 32-bit integer than `i32`.)

Comment: Using `.float` or `.double` in assembly runs the risk that a poor assembler will round improperly when converting. I expect the compiler generates `.long` to avoid that. Programmers using `.float` or `.double` should check the quality of their assembler in this regard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Feel free to edit the code.  Parentheses around return statements follow KNF, the remaining things are design decisions made to remove clutter from the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since there are only two assemblers the recognizes this syntax (Solaris as and GNU as) and both have high quality floating point parsing routines, there is little to worry about.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: good call, compiled for x86-64 SysV (where `unsigned long` is 64 bit), we happen to get lucky that gcc decides to assume the upper half of the 64-bit `i32` union member is zero, and uses `movd esi, xmm0` for type punning.  But without optimization the upper 4 bytes come from uninitialized stack space.  https://godbolt.org/g/CjxzQ8